# Minimal non-abelian groups -> Lie groups/algebras

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, lie-algebras

A group is called minimal non-abelian if it is non-abelian and all proper subgroups are abelian.

Does this notion also exist with Lie groups or algebras? As an example, consider the Lie algebra defined by the generators $\{e_1,e_2\}, [e_1,e_2]=e_2$. Do you have a paper at hand?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the question is? Sure, you can define such a notion for Lie algebras.

Comment: For a finite-dim Lie algebra in char zero: either it is simple anisotropic (in this case the characterization is unclear to me — for the reals, only $\mathfrak{so}_3$ works), or has the form $K\ltimes K^n$ with either an irreducible action or a nonzero nilpotent action when $n=2$ (3-dimensional Heisenberg).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These Lie algebras were called *semiabelian* by some authors. Some old papers are [On the structure of simple-semiabelian
Lie-algebras](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-111/issue-2/On-the-structure-of-simple-semiabelian-Lie-algebras/pjm/1102710571.pdf) by Farnsteiner and [On simple semiabelian $p$-adic lie algebras](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00927879208824390) by myself.

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\g}{\mathfrak{g}}$**Proposition.** *Let $K$ be a field of char. zero. Minimal non-abelian finite-dimensional Lie $K$-algebra fall into exactly 3 classes:*

(a) semidirect products $K\ltimes K^n$, with irreducible nontrivial action of $K$ on $K^n$.

(b) the Heisenberg Lie algebra $K\ltimes K^2$ (nilpotent non-trivial action)

(c) anisotropic simple Lie $K$-algebras that are minimal non-abelian.

Proof: this is easy. If $\g$ is not perfect, then it has a codimension 1 ideal, which by minimality is abelian, and hence has a decomposition $K\ltimes K^n$, where $K$ acts by multiples of an operator $T$. If $T$ doesn't act irreducibly, then there is a non-trivial proper subspace $W$, and by minimality $K\ltimes W$ is abelian. So $T$ has a nontrivial kernel. Write the characteristic polynomial of $T$ as $x^nP(x)$ with $P(0)\neq 0$. Then $K^n=\mathrm{Ker}(T^n)\oplus\mathrm{Ker}(P(T))$. So $\mathrm{Ker}(P(T))$ is a proper subspace, and then by minimality it has a trivial action of $T$, and hence it has to be zero, i.e., $T$ is nilpotent (and nonzero). Writing $T$ in Jordan form, we see that there is a proper $T$-invariant subspace on which $T$ acts non-trivially, as soon as the dimension is $\ge 3$.

If $\g$ is perfect, and non-semisimple, it has a Levi factor; this is a proper non-abelian subalgebra. Also if $\g$ is semisimple and non-simple, it has a non-abelian proper ideal. If $\g$ is simple and isotropic, it contains a copy of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$, so by mimimality should be $\mathfrak{sl}_2$, but this one is not minimal non-abelian. $\Box$

In case $K$ is algebraically closed, (a) is reduced the class of the 2-dimensional non-abelian Lie algebra, and (c) is the empty class.

In case $K$ consists of the reals, (a) also contains the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{h}(s)$ defined as the semidirect product $K\ltimes K^2$ with respect to the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}s& -1\\ 1 & s\end{pmatrix}$, which for $s\ge 0$ are pairwise non-isomorphic; and (c) is reduced to the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(3)$.

For general fields, the classification in (a) essentially corresponds to the classification of irreducible polynomials over $K$ (modulo rescaling $P(x)\mapsto P(sx)$) — of course this is not an easy problem but it's a very standard one. The classification in (c) is less clear to me.

As indicated [in the previous answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/444562/14094), it is solved for local fields of characteristic zero: Peter Müller, On simple semiabelian $p$-adic Lie algebras. Comm. Algebra 20 (1992), no. 4, 1041-1049. I don't have access to this paper, but the MR review says:

*In this paper the author classifies these algebras in the case where $k$ is a local field of characteristic $0$. His main result asserts that $L$ is simple-semiabelian if and only if $L$ is isomorphic to the commutator algebra of a finite-dimensional $k$-division algebra $D$ whose center $Z$ satisfies the following conditions: (a) there exists a prime number $p$ with $[D:Z]=p^2$; (b) $p$ divides $[Z:F]$ for every proper subfield $k\subset F\subset Z$.*

Comment: As far as I know, case (c) is still wide open. My old paper contains some more results. For instance, I give a construction over $\mathbb Q$ which becomes isomorphic to $\text{sl}_3(\bar{\mathbb Q})$ upon scalar extension. Btw, the published pdf is broken (bottom parts of the pages are missing). It seems that the copyright rules are quite restrictive, but it should be possible to email a scan of the offprint.